# Maven dependency inheritance in child pom from parent pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

As far as I know, maven uses `artifactId + groupId + classifier + type` to identify wether to merge or override dependencies in child pom from its parent module pom. Why do we need `type` here ? What could go wrong if this was done only by `artifactId + groupId + classifier` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we would not need the type for that. I don't see anything that would go wrong. On the other hand, I see no situation where the actual behaviour hurts.

Comment: Let us say parent pom have dependency X with type T1 and version V1. Child pom also have same dependency X with same maven coordinates but type T2 and version V2. Now after inheritance, child pom will have same dependency X with both version V1 and V2 ? (even though types are different)

Comment: You shouldn't have two artifacts that share groupId, artifactId and classifier, but have a different type. So in your example, both dependencies will have different classifier.